# Making divs fill up a containing div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been searching the site for an answer, and nothing I've come across seems to help. I'm trying to make it so that a default (and eventually user-specified) number of divs fill up the containing div like a grid. I'm trying to figure out how to make the size of the boxes I append to the parent change depending on how many are added, while always filling up the div, if that makes sense. So for instance, if I specify 9, I should have 3 rows and 3 columns. If I specify 62, then I'm looking for 16 rows and 16 columns, always filling up (or coming close to, anyway) the containing div. Here's a JSfiddle I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/1g9p59bx/1/ Here's the code as it is:

```
    var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");

function createGrid(numSquares){
    for(var i = 0; i < numSquares; i++){
            $('#g_area').append(d);
    }

    var squareSize = Math.floor(580/numSquares );
    $('.square').height(squareSize);
    $('.square').width(squareSize);
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid(64);

});
```

Comment: the example of 64 being 32x32 doesn't mean sense,  do you mean 32x2? Can you make it clear what the coding problem actually is

Comment: sorry, my math was way off. 64 would be a grid of 16x16. in my jsfiddle I have 64 columns on 1 row, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a lib for that? Masonery for example is there exactly for that and could reduce your amount of custom code.

Comment: That's something I'll certainly look into for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue you had was setting the square size to 1/64th of the height instead of 1/(64^.5) of the height. Essentially you where just making one row.  https://jsfiddle.net/1g9p59bx/7/

```
var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");


function createGrid(numSquares){
    var gridContainer = $('#g_area'); 
    for(var i = 0; i < numSquares; i++){
            gridContainer.append(d);
    }

    var squareSize = Math.floor(580/(Math.sqrt(numSquares)) );
    $('.square').height(squareSize);
    $('.square').width(squareSize);
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid(64);

});
```

Comment: Also you could go about this the other way and specify grid size instead of total squares for better performance. (ie) https://jsfiddle.net/1g9p59bx/8/

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it doesn't bleed out of the containing div?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a little jqueryplugin for that. You can call it in every container you like: `containerForGrid.createGrid(cols, rows)`

```js
(function($){

$.fn.createGrid = function(cols, rows) {
  
  // get width and height of sorrounding container
  var w = this.width()
  var h = this.height()
  
  // calculate width and height of one cell
  var colWidth = w / cols
  var rowHeight = h / rows
  
  // loop over all rows
  for(var i = rows; --i;){
  
      // loop over all cols
      for(var j = cols; --j;){
      
        $('<div>').css({
          width:colWidth,
          height:rowHeight,
          float:'left'
        }).appendTo(this)
      
      }
  
  }
  
}

})(jQuery)

jQuery('div').createGrid(10,10)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:1000px;height:500px">

</div>
```

Comment: Gotta get my reputation up, this is my first question here. As soon as I am able, I will. :)